# Jayway JsonPath Filter expression for inner array

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a JSON file in the format below.

```
{  
   "queryResponse":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Parent1",
         "childList":[  
            {  
               "id":"11",
               "type":"A"
            },
            {  
               "id":"12",
               "type":"B"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Parent2",
         "childList":[  
            {  
               "id":"21",
               "type":"B"
            },
            {  
               "id":"22",
               "type":"C"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Using jayway JsonPath, how do I get all the Parent nodes which have child nodes with type "B"?

These filter expressions returned an empty array:

- a wild card in the index like *$.queryResponse[?(@.childList[*].type=='B')]*
- a deep scan operator in the filter field like *$.queryResponse[?(@.childList..type=='B')]*

The only filter expression that is closest to what I want is the one with array index for ex: *$.queryResponse[?(@.childList[0].type=='A')]*

Comment: did you find a silution

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains` or `in` operator

```
$.queryResponse[?(@.childList[*].type contains 'B')]
```

**OR**

```
$.queryResponse[?('B' in @.childList[*].type )]
```